# nifi putHDFS writes to local filesystem

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi

## Challenge

I currently have two hortonworks clusters, a NIFI cluster and a HDFS cluster, and want to write to HDFS using NIFI.

On the NIFI cluster I use a simple GetFile connected to a PutHDFS.

When pushing a file through this, the PutHDFS terminates in success. However, rather than seeing a file dropped on my HFDS (on the HDFS cluster) I just see a file being dropped onto the local filesystem where I run NIFI.

This confuses me, hence my question:

#### How to make sure PutHDFS writes to HDFS, rather than to the local filesystem?

---

### Possibly relevant context:

- In the PutHDFS I have linked to the hive-site and core-site of the HDFS cluster (I tried updating all server references to the HDFS namenode, but with no effect)
- I don't use Kerberos on the HDFS cluster (I do use it on the NIFI cluster)
- I did not see anything looking like an error in the NIFI app log (which makes sense as it succesfully writes, just in the wrong place)
- Both clusters are newly generated on Amazon AWS with CloudBreak, and opening all nodes to all traffic did not help

Comment: Have you provided the path to `hdfs-site.xml` in the `Hadoop Configuration` property?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman Yes, both the hdfs-site and core-site are referenced there. (And I don't get the error that it cannot find them).

Comment: And the properties in the xml files are verified to be correct i.e. hostname details for datanode and namenode?

Comment: `*-site.xml` conf files are _optional_ and if the Hadoop client libs don't find them, they silently revert to hard-coded default values -- incl. "default FS is local" which is fine for unit tests -- expecting an overide via Java code.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for the explanation, that gives me something to investigate. Do you know what happens if they are found, but contain errors (like a wrong address for a namenode/datanode?)

Comment: Wrong svc address => connection attempt => exception.

Comment: Setting Log4J level to _DEBUG_ (for Hadoop `Configuration` class at least) should provide details about what goes wrong. On all NiFi nodes.

Answer (score -1):

Can you make sure that you are able move file from NiFi node to Hadoop using below command:-
hadoop fs -put

If you are able move your file using above command then you must check your Hadoop config file which you are passing in your PutHDFS processor.

Also, check that you don't have anyother flow running to make sure that no other flow is processing that file.

Comment: The nifi nodes run on a different cluster, so I don't think it is possible to run hadoop commands there (as the nifi cluster does not have HDFS).

Comment: I believe that you should have hadoop client installed on NiFi nodes.

Comment: Note that I am not talking about just 2 nodes, I am actually having 2 full clusters. -- Even if I were to have hdfs on the nifi cluster, then a put command would just commit it to the hdfs on the nifi cluster, not to the hdfs on my hdp cluster.